# Using styled google maps with Xamarin Android

Tags: google-maps, xamarin.android

Does anyone know how to use styled google maps with Xamarin android? Google recently added the ability to create a styled map from here https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/ and they show a sample of how to use it

```
private void setSelectedStyle() {
    MapStyleOptions style;
    switch (mSelectedStyleId) {
        case R.string.style_label_retro:
            // Sets the retro style via raw resource JSON.
            style = MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(this, R.raw.mapstyle_retro);
            break;
        case R.string.style_label_night:
            // Sets the night style via raw resource JSON.
            style = MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(this, R.raw.mapstyle_night);
            break;
        case R.string.style_label_grayscale:
            // Sets the grayscale style via raw resource JSON.
            style = MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(this, R.raw.mapstyle_grayscale);
            break;
        case R.string.style_label_no_pois_no_transit:
            // Sets the no POIs or transit style via JSON string.
            style = new MapStyleOptions("[" +
                    "  {" +
                    "    \"featureType\":\"poi.business\"," +
                    "    \"elementType\":\"all\"," +
                    "    \"stylers\":[" +
                    "      {" +
                    "        \"visibility\":\"off\"" +
                    "      }" +
                    "    ]" +
                    "  }," +
                    "  {" +
                    "    \"featureType\":\"transit\"," +
                    "    \"elementType\":\"all\"," +
                    "    \"stylers\":[" +
                    "      {" +
                    "        \"visibility\":\"off\"" +
                    "      }" +
                    "    ]" +
                    "  }" +
                    "]");
            break;
        case R.string.style_label_default:
            // Removes previously set style, by setting it to null.
            style = null;
            break;
        default:
            return;
    }
    mMap.setMapStyle(style);
```

Is there anyway to do this in Xamarin Android?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the release of the Xamarin google play map services v 32.961.0 https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps/ the MapStyleOptions is now supported.

To use a styled map create a new MapStyleOptions object

```
private void setSelectedStyle()
    {
        MapStyleOptions style;
        style = new MapStyleOptions("[" +
                    "  {" +
                    "    \"elementType\":\"geometry\"," +
                    "    \"stylers\":[" +
                    "      {" +
                    "        \"color\":\"#242f3e\"" +
                    "      }" +
                    "    ]" +
                    "  }," +
                    "  {" +
                    "    \"featureType\":\"transit\"," +
                    "    \"elementType\":\"geometry\"," +
                    "    \"stylers\":[" +
                    "      {" +
                    "        \"color\":\"#2f3948\"" +
                    "      }" +
                    "    ]" +
                    "  }" +
                    "]");
        map.SetMapStyle(style);
    }
```

and then call it in OnMapReady